# How to remotely submit a form from Radix Alert Dialog with form attribute?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, radix-ui

I'm using a Radix UI's Alert Dialog to prompt users to confirm that they want to delete a contact from their contact list in my nextjs 13 app:

[Screenshot of Alert Dialog modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsybM.png)

However the delete button (red 'Yes, button') is not triggering the onSubmit handler of the form - clicking it just closes the modal without deleting the contact.

The delete button is wired to a form remotely using the form attribute:

```js
const DeleteButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <button ref={ref} type="submit" form="edit-form" {...props}>
      Yes, delete
    </button>
  );
});
```

The form is set up as such:

```js
<form id='edit-form' onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
 ...form contents here...
</form>
```

The Alert Dialog is as per below:

```js
export default function Modal2({
  title,
  description,
  children, 
}) {
  return (
    <AlertDialog.Root>
      <AlertDialog.Trigger asChild>
        {children}
      </AlertDialog.Trigger>
      <AlertDialog.Portal>
        <AlertDialog.Overlay className={styles.overlay} />
        <AlertDialog.Content className={styles.content}>
          <AlertDialog.Title className={styles.title}>
            {title}
          </AlertDialog.Title>
          <AlertDialog.Description className={styles.description}>
            {description}
          </AlertDialog.Description>
          <div className={styles.actions}>
            <AlertDialog.Cancel className={`${styles.button} ${styles.cancel}`}>
              Cancel
            </AlertDialog.Cancel>
            <AlertDialog.Action
              className={`${styles.button} ${styles.action}`}
              asChild
            >
              <DeleteButton></DeleteButton>
            </AlertDialog.Action>
          </div>
        </AlertDialog.Content>
      </AlertDialog.Portal>
    </AlertDialog.Root>
  );
}
```

Tried forwarding refs, forwarding props and using the asChild prop as per composition section of docs but to no avail

The delete button in the Alert Dialog still doesn't trigger a form submission.

Please help as have been stuck here for quite sometime. Let me know if any other info required thanks in advance